# How can I pass string variable in JavaScript using Django URL?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

This is my script:

```
var id = $('#filename').val();
location.href = "{% url 'officelyapp:finalTemplate' privateId=id %}"
```

This is my url:

```
path('signature/template/merge/private/access/<str:privateId>/', views.finalTemplate, name='finalTemplate')
```

I get the following error attached below whenever I tried to load my page.

[Error Shown In Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epH4X.jpg)

I find this link: https://stackoverflow.com/.../get-javascript-variables... that passes JavaScript value like this:

```
window.location = "{% url 'your_view_name' 1234 %}".replace(/1234/, tmp.toString());
```

But this only works when one specifically writes a specific integer value in it like 1234 in the above line of code.

Comment: You can't pass something from the client to a Django template tag, the template is rendered server-side. If you don't like the `replace` solution you could change `privateId` to be a query/GET param?